# optimal control using scipy optimize

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy, scipy-optimize, scipy-optimize-minimize

I am trying to solve an optimal control problem where the cost function is J = x^T Q x + u^T R u subject to the x_dot = A x + B u and bounds for x and u. I know that there are some solvers like cvxpy, yalimp etc which could do this but I would like to do it myself to get a better ideas about the coding and possible addition of some other parameters in future.
I am attaching the code that I have written. It runs but returns the same value for all the time steps. I have stacked x and u as a single vector. I dont know if this is the right way to do it. I think the code could be written in a better/efficient way. All suggestions are welcome and really appreciate for any help in advance

Ash

```
import numpy as np
import sympy as sp
import scipy.optimize as opt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Optimal Control Problem
# Cost, J = x.transpose() * Q * x + u.transpose() * R * u
# x_dot = A*x + B*u
# x_min < x < x_max
# u_min < x < u_max


class mpc_opt():

    def __init__(self):
        self.Q = sp.diag(0.5, 1, 0)  # state penalty matrix, Q
        self.R = sp.eye(2) # input penalty matrix
        self.A = sp.Matrix([[-0.79, -0.3, -0.1],[0.5, 0.82, 1.23], [0.52, -0.3, -0.5]])  # state matrix 
        self.B = sp.Matrix([[-2.04, -0.21], [-1.28, 2.75], [0.29, -1.41]])  # input matrix

        self.t = np.linspace(0, 1, 30)


    # reference trajectory  ## static!!!
    def ref_trajectory(self, i):  # y = 3*sin(2*pi*omega*t)
        # y = 3 * np.sin(2*np.pi*self.omega*self.t[i])
        x_ref = sp.Matrix([0, 1, 0])
        return x_ref
        # return sp.Matrix(([[self.t[i]], [y], [0]]))

    def cost_function(self, U, *args):
        t = args
        nx, nu = self.A.shape[-1], self.B.shape[-1]
        x0 = U[0:nx]
        u = U[nx:nx+nu]
        u = u.reshape(len(u), -1)
        x0 = x0.reshape(len(x0), -1)
        x1 = self.A * x0 + self.B * u
        # q = [x1[0], x1[1]]
        # pos = self.end_effec_pose(q)
        traj_ref = self.ref_trajectory(t)
        pos_error = x1 - traj_ref
        cost = pos_error.transpose() * self.Q * pos_error + u.transpose() * self.R * u
        return cost

    def cost_gradient(self, U, *args):
        t = args
        nx, nu = self.A.shape[-1], self.B.shape[-1]
        x0 = U[0:nx]
        u = U[nx:nx + nu]
        u = u.reshape(len(u), -1)
        x0 = x0.reshape(len(x0), -1)
        x1 = self.A * x0 + self.B * u
        traj_ref = self.ref_trajectory(t)
        pos_error = x1 - traj_ref
        temp1 = self.Q * pos_error
        cost_gradient = temp1.col_join(self.R * u)
        return cost_gradient


    def optimise(self, u0, t):
        umin = [-2., -3.]
        umax = [2., 3.]
        xmin = [-10., -9., -8.]
        xmax = [10., 9., 8.]
        bounds = ((xmin[0], xmax[0]), (xmin[1], xmax[1]), (xmin[2], xmax[2]), (umin[0], umax[0]), (umin[1], umax[1]))

        U = opt.minimize(self.cost_function, u0, args=(t), method='SLSQP', bounds=bounds, jac=self.cost_gradient,
                         options={'maxiter': 200, 'disp': True})
        U = U.x
        return U


if __name__ == '__main__':
    mpc = mpc_opt()
    x0, u0, = sp.Matrix([[0.1], [0.02], [0.05]]), sp.Matrix([[0.4], [0.2]])
    X, U = sp.zeros(len(x0), len(mpc.t)), sp.zeros(len(u0), len(mpc.t))
    U0 = sp.Matrix([x0, u0])
    nx, nu = mpc.A.shape[-1], mpc.B.shape[-1]
    for i in range(len(mpc.t)):
        print('i = :', i)
        result = mpc.optimise(U0, i)
        x0 = result[0:nx]
        u = result[nx:nx + nu]
        u = u.reshape(len(u), -1)
        x0 = x0.reshape(len(x0), -1)
        U[:, i], X[:, i] = u0, x0
        # x0 = mpc.A * x0 + mpc.B * u
        U0 = result

plt.plot(X[0, :], '--r')
plt.plot(X[1, :], '--b')
plt.plot(X[2, :], '*r')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Please make sure that your example code compiles & runs before posting it. This sample raises an `IndexError: SLSQP Error: the length of bounds is not compatible with that of x0.` as your `bounds` variable is missing an element.

Comment: sorry for that. I just edited the code and it runs.

Comment: Perfect. Can you please explain: what is `x_dot`? is it the gradient of `x`?

Comment: x_dot is d/dt of x. (time derivative). In discrete form, it can be written as x(k+1) = A * x(k) + B * u(k), where k is the sampling time

Answer (score 2):

There is a similar MPC application that uses `Scipy.optimize.minimize` posted on the [process dynamics and control page for Model Predictive Control](https://apmonitor.com/pdc/index.php/Main/ModelPredictiveControl) (select Show Python MPC). It uses a first order linear system that could also be expressed in state space form. Here is a screen shot of the animation:

[image: Model Predictive Control]

Even though it is my course web-site, credit for this application goes to [Junho Park](https://www.linkedin.com/in/junho-park-90b86967/). There is also another tutorial for [linear MPC that uses MATLAB and Python Gekko](https://apmonitor.com/do/index.php/Main/TCLabF). This source code may help you as you are developing your application.

Answer (score 1):

Some points that I noticed:

1) Why do you use `sympy` matrices? It seems to me that `numpy.matrix` or `numpy.array` would be sufficient in your case. `sympy` is usually used when you want to work with symbolic expressions (e.g. symbolic differentiation).
*Note: Use the `@` operator for Matrix multiplication, e.g. in cost_gradient, you would use `temp1 = self.Q @ pos_error`*

2) You can use the [`staticmethod` decorator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#staticmethod) to denote a class method as static

3) Why do you use the optimization method `SLSQP`? It is used for constrained optimization (which does not apply to your problem). If we look at [the notes](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html) for `scipy.optimize.minimize` we can see that there are many algorithms used for unconstrained optimization (with bounds), which will probably converge faster. In most cases, you can just let the algorithm be decided automatically by not specifying anything.

4) Put the plot commands in the `main` method, not outside

Otherwise it looks alright. I haven't tested the functionality though.

Comment: Thank you for taking a look at this. 1) sympy matrix: I have non-linear symbolic expressions in my original work. Here I have just given a linear time invariant model. I agree numpy would be a better choice. 3) SLSQP: again for including constraints in the future. 
My main confusion is in the specification of the dynamics of the system specified by the equation ```x_dot = Ax + Bu```. The above code is to track the reference states given in ```x_ref``` but it wont.